# What does it mean for a set of measures to be compact and convex?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, convex-analysis

What does it mean for a set of measures to be compact and convex? The notion of compactness requires a topology, and the notion of convexity requires a vector space. What is the topology in the case of a set of measures, and what is the vector space? I am especially interested in measures over a $\sigma$-algebra whose universe is finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space of finite signed measures on a measurable space is a vector space in a natural way in which addition is done setwise. With this structure of a vector space, one has a natural notion of what it means for a set of measures to be convex.

There are two main linear topologies on this space, where a linear topology is a topology that makes scalar multiplication and addition continuous. If $(S,\mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space and $\mu$ is a signed measure on $(S,\mathcal{S})$, then there are, by the so-called Jordan decomposition, two uniquely determined nonnegative measures $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ such that $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$. The *variation norm* of $\mu$ is $\|\mu\|=\mu^+(S)+\mu^-(S)$. The induced topology is a linear topology.

If $X$ is a compact metrizable space (a number of generalizations are possible), we let $C(X)$ be the space of continuous functions endowed with the *uniform norm* or *sup-norm*. By the Riesz representation theorem, every continuous linear functional $p$ on this space corresponds to a finite signed Borel measure $\mu_p$ on $X$ so that
$$p(f)=\int f~\mathrm d\mu_p$$ for all $f\in C(X)$. This way, one can identify the dual space of $C(X)$ with the space of finite signed Borel measures on $X$. The dual norm is then exactly the variation norm. There is a smaller linear Hausdorff topology on the space of finite signed Borel measures on $X$, the *weak$^*$-topology*,which is the smallest topology on the space that makes the function
$$\mu\mapsto\int f~\mathrm d\mu$$
continuous for each $f\in C(X)$.

If $X$ is now a finite set, the discrete topology turns it into a compact metrizable space with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra being the power set of $X$. Every real valued function on $X$ is continuous. In this case,  finite signed Borel measures, as continuous linear functions, are determined by what they do to the points of $X$. If there are $n$ points in $X$, such a finite signed measure can be specified by $n$ coordinates and corresponds to a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The induced topology is linear and coincides with both the variation topology and the weak$^*$-topology (they differ for infinite $X$). As a matter of fact, there is only one linear topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Hausdorff property.

If $X$ is finite but one looks at smalller $\sigma$-algebras, one can do something similar. There is a one to one correspondece between $\sigma$-algebras on a finite set and partitions on the set, where the corresponding partition cells consists of minimal nonempty measurable sets. If the partition has $m$ cells, we can again identify finite signed measures on the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra with $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Thanks. Since you deleted the comments to my original post, would you mind please adding to your answer that (1) the induced topology is not only linear, but is also with the Hausdorff property, and (2) that the one linear topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Hausdorff property is the Euclidean topology.

Comment: I edited that the weak*-topology s Hausdorff. For 2), it already states that there is only one linear Hausdorff topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.